Springboot @Retryable
Springboot version: 3.3.2
Java: 21
import io.cloudevents.CloudEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.NoHttpResponseException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyClient {

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public MyClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(createInterceptors());
  }

  @Retryable(
      retryFor = {NoHttpResponseException.class, RestClientException.class},
      noRetryFor = {MyRunTimeException.class},
      maxAttempts = 3,
      backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 1),
      listeners = {"MyRetryListener"})
  public CloudEvent getDecision(CloudEvent cloudEvent, String endpoint) {

    HttpEntity<CloudEvent> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(cloudEvent);

    ResponseEntity<CloudEvent> responseEntity =
        restTemplate.exchange(endpoint, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, CloudEvent.class);

    return responseEntity.getBody();
  }

  private List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> createInterceptors() {
    return List.of(
        (request, body, execution) -> {
          try {
            ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
            HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
            if (!statusCode.is2xxSuccessful()) {
              throw new MyRunTimeException(
                  "Failed to create decision: response status %s".formatted(statusCode));
            } else {
              return response;
            }
          } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new MyRunTimeException("Unexpected error: %s".formatted(ex.getMessage()), ex);
          }
        });
  }
}

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryCallback;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryContext;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyRetryListener implements RetryListener {

  public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(
      RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
    log.error(
        "My retry attempt {} failed due to: {}", context.getRetryCount(), throwable.getMessage());
  }
}

I'm confused about the Springboot @Retryable behaviour, I have especially add exception MyRunTimeException in noRetryFor, but the @Retryable is still executed once for MyRunTimeException
The RestTemplate interceptor throws MyRunTimeException if the response status code is not 2xx. So I created @SpringbootTest and simulate the response status is 500.
I was able to find the error log  MyRetryListener    : My retry attempt 1 failed due to: Failed to create decision: response status 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR if the response status is not 2xx. It only retried once. May I ask how can I fix this issue?

The logic there in the RetryTemplate like this:
    catch (Throwable e) {

                lastException = e;

                try {
                    registerThrowable(retryPolicy, state, context, e);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new TerminatedRetryException("Could not register throwable", ex);
                }
                finally {
                    doOnErrorInterceptors(retryCallback, context, e);
                }

                if (canRetry(retryPolicy, context) && !context.isExhaustedOnly()) {

That registerThrowable() calls eventually a RetryContextSupport:
public void registerThrowable(Throwable throwable) {
    this.lastException = throwable;
    if (throwable != null)
        count++;
}

So, that is really expected to see that 1 in logs of your MyRetryListener.onError().
That next if (canRetry(retryPolicy, context) after interceptor is not going to be fulfilled because of your  noRetryFor = {MyRunTimeException.class}. Therefore so far all good.

Thank for reply @Artem Bilan, I finally understood the code in RetryTemplate, so the MyRetryListener will log the error only once if the Exception is not in the list.

Correct. That is error situation anyway. And since it is not retryable it will be thrown back to the caller. Therefore it feels natural to have it reported in that onError() anyway.
